# Background-image for table

Tags: html, css

I am trying to apply a background image for table cells which display on mobile phone. As the image is in a large size, so I need to make it responsive for different screen sizes ( iphone, android, etc). So I used CSS like following:

```
TABLE TR{

background-image: url("../images/bg.png");
-webkit-background-size: cover;
-moz-background-size: cover;
-o-background-size: cover;
background-size: cover;
height: 85px;

}
```

The table has two td: ( I can't change those two td, as they are used for styling info in table cell)

```
TABLE .td1 {

text-align: left;

width: 80%;
padding-top: 0px;
padding-bottom: 33px;

}

TABLE .td2 {
text-align: left;
line-height: 14px;
width: 9%;
}
```

Then, it looks like, background img just break at td1 and re-peat at td2:

My questions is how to adjust the css and make the whole TR cell have the background image without break at td1?

[image]

below is fiddle code, I don't know how to upload image to there.
this is just the structure of my HTML code: [HTML CODE](http://jsfiddle.net/aem2D/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have to use Tables (is it an `HTML` email?) or can you just use a div layout? If you must use the `TABLE` then try altering the CSS in the code to look like this:

```
tr {display: block;}
td {display: inline-block; background: transparent;}
```

Comment: Excellent. Glad to help. Up the answer if you want :-)

Comment: Hi Phlume, can I control the with of background image? I found it can only have a minimum width of 400px...perhaps I should re-size the original image to a proper ratio? ( original size 1029x223). I dragged my browser, and it stop responsive to browser width at about 400px width.

Comment: as a best practice I try to always size the image as needed, yes.